App script variable not updating on function run
I am creating an app script for minesweeper in google sheets and i need to get the selected cell but the variable is not updating and it is changing the background of the same cell
function highlightSelectedCell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var selectedRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  // var selectedCellAddress = selectedRange.getA1Notation();
  
  // Clear previous formatting
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  range.setBackground(null);
  
  // Highlight selected cell
  if (selectedRange.getNumRows() == 1 && selectedRange.getNumColumns() == 1) {
    selectedRange.setBackground("#0000FF");
  }
}



function sweeper() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let game = ss.getSheets()[0];
  let isMine = ss.getSheets()[1];
  let numberOfNearMines = ss.getSheets()[2];
  let mines = randInt(15,20);
  let statusBox = game.getRange(1,14);
  let gameBoard = game.getRange("gameBoard");

  isMine.getRange(1,1).setValue(mines);
  isMine.getRange(2,2,11,11).setValue(" ");
  statusBox.setValue("Loading...");

  for (var counter = 0; counter < mines; counter = counter + 1) {
    placeMine();
  }

  // for (var counter = 0; counter < 100; counter = counter + 1){
  //   let row = (Math.floor(counter/10))+2;
  //   let colom = counter - Math.floor(counter/10);

  //   if(counter == 10) {
  //     numberOfNearMines.getRange("A1").setValue(colom + "," + row);
  //   }
  //   //let cell = numberOfNearMines.getRange()
  // }
  statusBox.setValue("Loaded");

  for(var counter = 0; counter>-1; counter = counter + 1) {
    gameLoop();
  }
}

function randInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

function placeMine() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let isMine = ss.getSheets()[1];
  let cell = isMine.getRange(randInt(2,11),randInt(2,11));
  if(cell.getValue() == "M") {
    placeMine();
    return
  }
  cell.setValue("M");
}

function gameLoop() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let game = ss.getSheets()[0];
  let isMine = ss.getSheets()[1];
  let statusBox = game.getRange(1, 14);
  let gameBoard = game.getRange("gameBoard");

  highlightSelectedCell();
  return
}


my app script runs a function to highlight the current selected cell but when running the function multiple times the cell to change dose not update

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About the variable is not updating and it is changing the background of the same cell, can I ask you about the details of the variable? About my app script runs a function to highlight the current selected cell but when running the function multiple times the cell to change dose not update, can I ask you about the details of the function and the cell? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

I don't have time to take a good look but be carefull with conditionals like this (selectedRange.getNumRows() == 1 && selectedRange.getNumColumns() == 1) should be ((selectedRange.getNumRows() == 1) && (selectedRange.getNumColumns() == 1))

Hi Parker, Does the active cell actually changes? I suggest to log the selectedRange.getA1Notation() to the console to be sure of that.
By the way, this is not related to your question but is suggest to avoid getSheets()[x]
for getSheetByName('')
